# Get the name of a Geoserver store based on the layer name

Tags: geoserver, gsconfig

Is there a way to get the name of the Store that the layer belongs using gsconfig?

I have two different Stores registered in my geoserver and I need programmatically to be able to know which store each layer belongs to.

In the gsconfig documentation I see there is a get_store function but it accepts as argument only the store name (or the workspace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small function in python to do this.
Essentially if you get the resource base then you can get the name of the store as:

```
def get_store_name(layer_name, workspace):
  # get the name of the store
  cat = Catalog(location, user, pass)
  resource = cat.get_resource(layer_name, workspace)
  store_name = resource.store.name
  return store_name
```